# There exists $n$ consecutive integers divisible by nontrivial $m$'th powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Prove that for any positive integers $m$ and $n$ , there exists a set of $n$ consecutive positive integers each of which is divisible by a number of the form $d^m$, where $d$ is some positive integer not equal to $1$.

I don't know how to approach this question.

Comment: Hint: Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: What if you take $d=1$?

Comment: haven't studied that yet :p. Any other way?

Comment: @RickDecker that's a loophole. I should have closed that.

Comment: The first term of such a sequence is precisely what CRT guarantees

Comment: So just to clarify, $d$ is allowed to depend on the "each of which" integer?

Comment: @HenningMakholm have to. isn't it?

Comment: @D.K.: Yes -- perhaps I'm just slow.

Comment: @HenningMakholm not slower than me XD

Comment: Closely related: [Is there a sequence of 5 consecutive positive integers such that none are square free](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1191337/)

Comment: [Blog article about this](https://blog.plover.com/math/consecutive-squarefull.html)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** The trick is to *start by* choosing the $d_k$s such that $(d_k)^m \mid x+k$. If you make the $d_k$s mutually coprime (say, choose different primes), then the Chinese Remainder Theorem will tell you what $x$ is.

Answer (score 1):

For the OP we can choose $S$ below to be the $m$'th powers of elements of any sequence of coprimes (e.g. the primes, or coprimes generated as in [Euclid's proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30133/242) of infinitely many primes).

**Hint** $\ $ If $\, S\subset \Bbb Z\,$ contains infinitely many pairwise coprime integers $\,s_i\,$  then for all $\,n> 0\,$ there is a sequence of $\,n\,$ consecutive integers each of which is a multiple of some element of $\,S,\,$ since there exists an integer $\,x\,$ satisfying $\, \color{#0a0}{s_1\mid x\!+\!1},\,\ s_2\mid x\!+\!2,\, \ldots,\ \color{#c00}{s_n\mid x\!+\!n},\,$ by applying CRT to

$$\begin{align} \color{#0a0}{x\equiv -1\!\!\pmod{\!s_1}}\\ 
x\equiv -2\!\!\pmod{\!s_2}\\ 
\cdots\qquad \quad\cdots\quad\     \\ 
\color{#c00}{x\equiv -n\!\!\pmod{\!s_n}}\end{align}$$

**Note** $ $ [CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242) guarantees that a solution exists when the moduli are pairwise coprime. In fact there are *infinitely* many solutions $\,x + k\:\! \color{#0a0}{s_1}\cdots \color{#c00}{s_n},\,$ for every integer $\:\!k$.