# Consecutive composite numbers using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-gaps

## Consecutive Composite Numbers

Define a list of the first $n$ prime numbers $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n$.

Create a set of $n$ congruences

\begin{align*}
x + 1 &\equiv 0 \pmod{p_1} \\
x + 2 &\equiv 0 \pmod{p_2} \\
&\vdots \\
x + n &\equiv 0 \pmod{p_n}
\end{align*}

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT), there exists a unique solution $x$.

The solution $x$ gives the start of a sequence of $n$ consecutive composite numbers:

$$x + 1, x + 2, \ldots, x + n$$

## Example

Here's a C example to generate [21 consecutive composites](https://godbolt.org/z/74saqYEfb) using the above CRT method.

```
x+1 = 18242056294531940584645872728
x+2 = 18242056294531940584645872729
x+3 = 18242056294531940584645872730
x+4 = 18242056294531940584645872731
x+5 = 18242056294531940584645872732
x+6 = 18242056294531940584645872733
x+7 = 18242056294531940584645872734
x+8 = 18242056294531940584645872735
x+9 = 18242056294531940584645872736
x+10 = 18242056294531940584645872737
x+11 = 18242056294531940584645872738
x+12 = 18242056294531940584645872739
x+13 = 18242056294531940584645872740
x+14 = 18242056294531940584645872741
x+15 = 18242056294531940584645872742
x+16 = 18242056294531940584645872743
x+17 = 18242056294531940584645872744
x+18 = 18242056294531940584645872745
x+19 = 18242056294531940584645872746
x+20 = 18242056294531940584645872747
x+21 = 18242056294531940584645872748
```

## Question

The common methods to generate consecutive composites are

$$\overbrace{(n+1)! + 2, \ (n+1)! + 3, \ \ldots, \ (n+1)! + (n+1)}^{\text{n composites}}$$

$$\overbrace{n!+2,n!+3,...,n!+n}^{\text{n-1 composites}}$$

$$\overbrace{n\#+2,n\#+3,…n\#+n}^{\text{n-1 composites (Primorials)}}$$

I'm curious what are the reasons this Chinese Remainder method to generate `consecutive composite numbers` isn't as well known?

Comment: Is the CRT method to `generate consecutive composites` referenced in those duplicate questions? It wasn't clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is a very well-known method and is used in many prior answers, e.g. see the linked dupes (there are *many* more that can be found by searching). [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1892205/242) in the first dupe I prove a generalization that there is a consecutive sequence of $n$ integers containing factors from any infinite set whose elements are pairwise coprime.

Comment: I agree that the CRT method is quite lovely, and also helps to find intervals of composite numbers that are (much) smaller than those found using the factorial method. However, one nice feature of the factorial method is its simplicity. It is convincing to someone who doesn't have the CRT in their tool kit, as it just requires a bit of very basic arithmetic.